# Can wearing big tefillin be seen as yuhara?

Tags: tefilin, derech-eretz-manners, yuhara

I am interested in getting 4x4 tefillin in order to have more mehudar parshiyot, but I'm worried about wearing them in a kehila where they wear smaller tefillin. I'm especially concerned about wearing them in the presence of a tzadik or gadol who is wearing smaller tefillin.

Can this actually be seen as yuhara, gaaveh and lack of cavod, or is it something that would not be an issue?

Comment: If you're just seeking opinions, I couldn't care less what size tfillin you wear. I imagine most people feel similarly.

Comment: Many don't consider 4x4 tefillin a good chumra because it's hard to put them on in the right spots on your body and have them stay. (Someone here did some experiments and posted an answer; can't find it now.) If you want nice parshiot you can get those for "normal" size tefillin too.

Comment: Don't draw attention to your own tefillin and more than likely no one else will also. And if you're asked, tell them it's the inside that matters, not the outside :D

Comment: I've seen some people with 4x4 tefillin and honestly it doesn't stand out as much, nor that anybody actually pay attention to it - also considering that Chabad usually prefer this size. As Double AA mentioned, 4x4 tefillin have their disadvantages as well.

Comment: In orech chayim 11 we are told wear a tallit gadol with tzitzit passed through 2 holes would be gaaveh,  I would think that would be even less of an issue

Comment: @ Double AA I'm not (and never am) just seeking opinions,  I'm seeking sourced information from poskim and gedolim.

Comment: The reason Chabad wears large tefillin is that is the opinion of the Shulchan Aruch Harav as to the proper size of tefillin. Other Ashkenazim follow a different opinion. So this is not a gaava issue, it is a halachic issue you should ask your rav. If you are not chabad, you should probably get regular tefillin, and pay extra for a better sofer.

Comment: According to many, smaller tefillin are actually more mehudar, based on a maamar Chaza"l (Menachot 34) that states that the correct spot on the head can fit two battim, which clearly is not the case for larger tefillin.